# Why isn't webpack watch working?

Tags: javascript, json, webpack

I'm having a quite peculiar issue. Everything was working just fine but suddenly `webpack watch` started throwing the following error:

```
ERROR in multi ./src/index.js watch
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'watch' in 'C:\xampp\htdocs\ReactJS\RecipeBox' @ multi ./src/index.js watch
```

I have no clue as to why this is happening, especially given that `webpack` runs just fine and transpiles everything as intended. I want it to watch my files as I work and this is where the problem arises. I'd appreciate any help.

I'm not sure how relevant they are, but shots of both my project structure and dependencies in the `package.json` file are displayed below.

**Project structure**

[image]

**Dependencies - package.json**

[image]

Comment: You want to run `webpack --watch`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Arguments you pass to the webpack CLI are used as entry points. You want to use the `--watch` option, not add `watch` as an entry. The correct command is:

```
webpack --watch
```

Comment: Thank you. I knew I was missing something but wasn't sure what.